# Launching process from CLI vs from Task Manager

Tags: command-line, windows-explorer

So, Windows Explorer has crashed on me yet again, and now my task bar is gone. But I know that all I have to do is to run Explorer again, and the task bar will reappear.

If I launch Explorer via `taskmgr`, everything works - the task bar will reappear just like I wanted.
But sometimes I try to run Explorer via `cmd.exe`. The reason why I do this is irrelevant.

Nope. Nothing happens. It just opens "Libraries" in a new window and doesn't restore the task bar.

Here is the described behavior, captured on GIF. I make sure that explorer isn't running, then I run it via CLI, and after that - via `taskmgr`. Notice how the task bar appears (*at the top of the screen*) only if I run explorer via `taskmgr`.

[image]

Here's the question: why and how does it happen? `taskmgr` allows me to run arbitrary task, which should be identical to what `cmd` offers. Unless `taskmgr` checks specifically if I try to run `explorer` and adds some mysterious command line parameters in such cases, it should be no different at all from my attempt to run Explorer via CLI. And yet somehow Explorer knows to restore the task bar only when it's run via `taskmgr`, so there must be something different about its execution. In that case, what is different - is it CLI invocation, or something else entirely?

Answer (score 1):

CLI switches aren't the only thing that can control the behavior of the Windows
processes.

The process invocation via CLI and via Task Manager are actually quite
different, and this footprint can be used in multiple ways.

### CWD (the answer)

The reason why Explorer doesn't start task bar is that when executed from CLI,
it's working directory is different when it's executed from the Task Manager.
In the posted GIF the CWD is set to `Z:\`, while `taskmgr` sets it to
`C:\Windows`. It knows that it should set it to `C:\Windows`, since
`C:\Windows\` is the first folder in the `PATH` environment variable that
contains `explorer.exe`. This detail is enough to make a difference -
simulating this in `cmd`:

```
C:\> cd /d C:\windows
C:\windows> explorer
```

...indeed restores the task bar as expected.

#### `CreateProcess`

The execution of the processes can be also controlled with a `STARTUPINFO`
Windows structure, that is used by WinAPI's `CreateProcess` function, the main
function to open new processes in Windows.

I wrote a program to test the differences between `STARTUPINFO` for programs
launched by CMD and for programs launched by Task Manager:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    memset(&si, 0, sizeof(si));
    GetStartupInfo(&si);

    FILE *fp = fopen("Z:\\output.txt",  "a");
    if (!fp) {
        return 1;
    }
    fprintf(fp, "cb:              %08x\n", si.cb);
    fprintf(fp, "lpDesktop:       %s\n", si.lpDesktop);
    fprintf(fp, "dwX:             %d\n", si.dwX);
    fprintf(fp, "dwY:             %d\n", si.dwY);
    fprintf(fp, "dwXSize:         %d\n", si.dwXSize);
    fprintf(fp, "dwYSize:         %d\n", si.dwYSize);
    fprintf(fp, "dwXCountChars:   %d\n", si.dwXCountChars);
    fprintf(fp, "dwYCountChars:   %d\n", si.dwYCountChars);
    fprintf(fp, "dwFillAttribute: %d\n", si.dwFillAttribute);
    fprintf(fp, "dwFlags:         %d\n", si.dwFlags);
    fprintf(fp, "wShowWindow:     %d\n", si.wShowWindow);
    fprintf(fp, "hStdInput:       %08x\n", si.hStdInput);
    fprintf(fp, "hStdOutput:      %08x\n", si.hStdOutput);
    fprintf(fp, "hStdError:       %08x\n", si.hStdError);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

I quickly arrived with the following results - running the test program via CMD results in following:

```
cb:              00000044
lpDesktop:       Winsta0\Default
dwX:             0
dwY:             0
dwXSize:         0
dwYSize:         0
dwXCountChars:   0
dwYCountChars:   0
dwFillAttribute: 0
dwFlags:         256
wShowWindow:     0
hStdInput:       000001d8
hStdOutput:      000001dc
hStdError:       000001dc
```

while running it via `taskmgr` results in following:

```
cb:              00000044
lpDesktop:       Winsta0\Default
dwX:             0
dwY:             0
dwXSize:         0
dwYSize:         0
dwXCountChars:   0
dwYCountChars:   0
dwFillAttribute: 0
dwFlags:         1
wShowWindow:     1
hStdInput:       ffffffff
hStdOutput:      ffffffff
hStdError:       ffffffff
```

We can see that they obviously differ from each other - for example, CLI
doesn't want the program to show any window, and taskmgr closes all standard
I/O handles. Any program can use this information to control its behavior -
even if it's not intuitive to the end user, it is fully possible.

#### `ShellExecute`

The other standard way to run processes is a WinAPI's `ShellExecute` function.
According to [this post](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/14778/),
`ShellExecute` does following:

1. Determines the type of file by searching the Windows Registry.
2. Enumerates the allowed shell commands (verbs).
3. Retrieves the command line for the specified verb.
4. Constructs the command-line switches.
5. Calls `CreateProcess()` to start the process pointed to by the retrieved
   command line.

This function is entirely capable of manipulating CLI parameters of the given process - in fact, you can try to spawn a process for a text file... and `ShellExecute` will run default application responsible for opening text files, using parameters as instructed by the Windows Registry. This is what Task Manager does: if you try to run new task pointing to a text file, it figures out that it should open your default text editor.